# Shipping conditions based on a custom field

Tags: commerce

I have custom fields in my customer profiles (so I don't use the dynamic addressfield) like name, streetname, number, postalcode and country. Now I would like to create 3 different shipping services with conditions based on different countries.

For example:

Shipping 1 = Netherlands, Shipping 2 = Germany, Shipping 3 = Belgium.

In my customer profiles I have a custom field called 'country' which have the values Netherlands, Germany and Belgium in a select list.

When setting a condition for the selected shipping service I am unable to select the correct data selector (order address component comparison doesn't work, cause that only works with the dynamic addressfield). I tried using 'entity has field' but that doesn't seem to work either (or I used the wrong settings?).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I was sure it was asked here already, but cannot find it. If I'm right, I hope someone else will be able to point you to it. If I'm wrong, well, I'd like to see it too. Limiting shipping options, like "this item is too fragile to send via regular mail" seems perfectly reasonable need.